# In-app purchase rejected

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

my app just got rejected due to the following issue:
incorrectly implemented receipt validation, so it does not properly distinguish between the review (sandbox) environment and the production environment

Everything works fine on my sandbox environment However not too sure why this is occurring. I've attached my code here hope someone could help me take a look what i might have missed out. This code is triggered when the Transaction Observer receives a payment queue call.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define STORE_URL @"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
#endif

#ifdef RELEASE
#define STORE_URL @"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
#endif

-(void)retrieveJSONReceipt:(NSData *)receipt andTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction{
    //Get the JSON receipt
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *requestContents = @{@"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]};
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&error];
    if (!requestData) {
        NSLog(@"No requestData with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    //Create a POST request with the receipt NSData
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:STORE_URL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
    [storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

    void (^completionHandler)(NSData *, NSURLResponse *, NSError *);
    completionHandler = ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){
            NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            if (!jsonResponse) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }else{
                if ([self validateJSONReceipt:jsonResponse]) {
                    [self verifyPurchaseInReceipt:jsonResponse[@"receipt"] andTransaction:transaction];
                }else{
                    [self removeHUD];
                }
            }
        }
    };
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession]dataTaskWithRequest:storeRequest
                               completionHandler:completionHandler]resume];
}
```

This is the screenshot I received back from Apple. Unsure what they are trying to point out here. Am I supposed to see something like "This account is not a Test User Account" if i am logged into a normal account?

[image]

Comment: IIRC, they use a sandbox account to test, so your app needs to check if the receipt is a valid prod receipt, and if you get back a particular error code you check it as a sandbox receipt instead.

Comment: THanks, when should I conduct these checks though? Upon app launch or when adding a payment? Also, doesn't the code above already do that?

Comment: You need to check every time you check a receipt. Looks like that will probably need to go in your `verifyPurchaseInReceipt:andTransaction:` method.